# Query cache efficiency

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm using MySQLTuner.pl to optimize my site.... though I'm not entirely sure how to resolve some of these issues and am wondering if someone can help me out.

I'm running 16GB of RAM with the following MySQL settings:

```
key_buffer              = 1024M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 1500
table_cache            = 256
thread_concurrency     = 4

query_cache_limit       = 2M
query_cache_size        = 32M
query_cache_type        = 1

tmp_table_size          = 512M
max_heap_table_size     = 128M
join_buffer_size        = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
```

Here's the output of my tuner

```
   -------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.6-log
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: -Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 98M (Tables: 402)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 16K (Tables: 1)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 17

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 10s (1K q [132.400 qps], 443 conn, TX: 119K, RX: 82K)
[--] Reads / Writes: 100% / 0%
[--] Total buffers: 1.2G global + 130.6M per thread (1500 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 192.4G (1225% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/1K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 0% (2/1500)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 1.0G/72.5M
[!!] Key buffer hit rate: 72.3% (47 cached / 13 reads)
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 875 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 2 sorts)
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 23% (48 on disk / 201 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (2 created / 443 connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 4% (128 open / 2K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 3% (257/7K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (449 immediate / 449 locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 16.0K/8.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    query_cache_limit (> 2M, or use smaller result sets)
    table_cache (> 128)
```

When I decrease `query_cache_limit` and `table_cache` it doesn't appear to have any effect.  I have restarted MySQL within the last 24 hours which could be part of the issue.

**update**

After running `SHOW STATUS LIKE  '%cache%'` the output is

```
Variable_name   Value
Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
Binlog_cache_use    0
Com_assign_to_keycache  0
Qcache_free_blocks  436
Qcache_free_memory  23551488
Qcache_hits 72553
Qcache_inserts  26954
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   7164
Qcache_queries_in_cache 5877
Qcache_total_blocks 12347
Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
Ssl_session_cache_size  0
Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
Threads_cached  3
```

Comment: By "effect" you mean better performance or less warnings from MySQLTuner?

Comment: better performance.  I'm expecting a huge server load the beginning of December and will need every bit of performance

Comment: The warning does only mean that your server does not have enough RAM (and therefore will swap) when it uses all RAM that you allowed it to use. So reducing query cache size will maybe make the warning go away but will not directly increase performance. Anyway, it seems that your query cache is not used at all, so you should check why this is the case. (However, query cache is much less important than index cache.)

Comment: `table_cache` is good, dun set it too high too, your query cache efficiency is 0%, is it too many writes? try `show status like '%cache%';` and also, `mysql <<<"show table status"| sed -e "s/\t/|/g"|cut -d '|' -f 10,1|grep -v "|0$"`, these are the table u ought to optimize

Comment: @ajreal - what will that do?  How do I execute that?  @andreKR Would it kill my server if it's setup the way it is for me to get a huge amount of traffic in regards to RAM?  Is the query cache size on a per-query basis?

Comment: how about `Created_tmp_files` in `show status` ? if the table is not optimize (non-zero data_free in `show table status`), probably worth to optimize the table, also log the slow query for revision

Comment: @webnet - is the same as `show table status` look for `Data_free` column

Comment: @ajreal `Created_tmp_files` is 5.  I'm already logging slow queries and queries without indexes.  This report is what I was concerned with.

Comment: what are the slow queries saying ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any slow queries right now.  But I'm expecting to have about 800%+ traffic increase for a 2 week span the beginning of december which is why I was inquiring about this

Comment: @webnet : what is the time u set for slow query? if no slow query, and no-index query, pretty much is optimized, good job then, consider something like memcache? cache your web pages during/before traffic spikes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this website helpful in optimizing my own mysql server: http://www.omh.cc/mycnf/

It allows you to tune your variables and know what the total ram capacity will be. You need to optimize for 60% ram usage. So try to lower your total memory footprint to about 60% to 70% of your total ram. If you have other stuff running on the same machine, you probably need to reduce that number. Forget `Query cache`, it's not going to add too much value, but `Table cache` should improve your performance if done right.

Try reducing the number of connections and keeping your total memory footprint under 60% of total system memory.

Comment: Offline. Any alternative?

Comment: @Slowaways here is an alternative: http://mysqlcalculator.com/. That calculator does not seem to work anymore.